# Enabling Magento2 Database Profiler

Tags: magento2, profiler

How to enable Magento2's database profiler ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had to do a little digging in the core code base found the following details:

First in app/etc/env.php we have to add "profiler" key in the connection array:

```
return array (
  ....
  'db' => 
  array (
    .....
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        ....
        'profiler' => [
            'class' => '\Magento\Framework\DB\Profiler',
            'enabled' => true,
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  ......
);
```

Secondly in the index.php or pub/index.php (depending on the server Vhost configuration) of the application have to add this extra html code:

```
$bootstrap->run($app); //This should be the last line
//After Than add these
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $res */
$res = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
/** @var Magento\Framework\DB\Profiler $profiler */
$profiler = $res->getConnection('read')->getProfiler();
echo "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Time <br/>[Total Time: ".$profiler->getTotalElapsedSecs()." secs]</th>";
echo "<th>SQL [Total: ".$profiler->getTotalNumQueries()." queries]</th>";
echo "<th>Query Params</th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($profiler->getQueryProfiles() as $query) {
    /** @var Zend_Db_Profiler_Query $query*/
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', number_format(1000 * $query->getElapsedSecs(), 2), 'ms', '</td>';
    echo '<td>', $query->getQuery(), '</td>';
    echo '<td>', json_encode($query->getQueryParams()), '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

The output will look something like this:

[image]

**Warning: This will mess up any ajax request due to the profiler output being rendered**

Comment: Hi, what do you use the database profiler for?

Comment: Basically just to see what all query were executed for the page, query time and query params

Comment: Thank you. I created internal issue MAGETWO-47970 to track creating documentation for the database profiler. If you have any real-world observations or advice, please let us know. (IOW, is there a trick or advice to interpreting results? Anything to look for in particular?)

Comment: I have added a few modification to my answer and a screen shot of the output, hope this will help better interpret the result of the DB profiler.

Comment: [Atish](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/33653/atish-goswami), I finally created a topic for this. I verified it on 2.1; I'm sure it works on 2.0.x as well. We'd like to give you credit for it seeing as how you figured it out. Do you have a web site? We could link to that. Thanks

Comment: @SteveJohnson That's so nice of you :), my website is http://atishgoswami.com/

Comment: @AtishGoswami, [Done](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/db-profiler/db-profiler.html). Your web site doesn't have anything on it, want me to change the URL?